# Stripe webhook returns 301 error but works in localhost

Tags: django-rest-framework, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have implemented a Stripe webhook to handle payment events in my Django rest framewrok application. When I test the webhook locally, it works as expected and I am able to receive and process the payment events. However, when I deploy the application  and try to use the webhook, I receive a 301 error from Stripe. There is no response from the webhook call as shown in Stripe dashboard. The webhook URL is reachable and I am able to access it without any issues. I have also checked the logs and there are no errors on the server side, which mean that the content of post function is not executed.

I am not sure what is causing this issue and would appreciate any help in troubleshooting and fixing it. Thank you.

The webhook url

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('stripe-webhook', stripe_webhook.as_view()),
]
```

The webhook function is as shown:

```py
class stripe_webhook(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        #verify webhook request
        print(request.body)
        payload = request.body
        sig_header = request.headers['STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
        event = None

        try:
            event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
                payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
            )
        except ValueError as e:
            # Invalid payload
            raise e
        except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
            # Invalid signature
            raise e

        # Handle the event
        if event['type'] == 'payment_intent.succeeded':
            payment_intent = event['data']['object']
            print(payment_intent)
        else:
            print('Unhandled event type {}'.format(event['type']))

        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might happen to have a middleware or a load balancer for the server hosting your webhook endpoint which might explain `301` status code. Just a guess though. You would likely want to talk to your hosting provider to see if they can shed any lights on why the requests are being redirected once they come in.

Comment: So the issue more or less related to hosting services? I am currently using free hosting services provided by railway. If the issue come from there, I might need to seek for other hosting services.

Comment: It returns status 200 after I shift the hosting service to render. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ch'ngGuoYang How did you go about this? I am using Render.com hosting service and I get this 301 ERR in my webhook.

Comment: I not sure how this be solved exactly but I guess it related to redirection between http and https. Do any part of your site involve http to https redirect?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this was an invalid Webhook secret credentials.